# Google cloud functions python37 with storage trigger won't deploy and won't give any logs

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I tried deploying with gcloud from the terminal, and I tried via the UI, I get the same error during deployment (build works) in the *deployment logs*:

> Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Function cannot be initialized.

And gcloud tells me the following:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=13, message=Function deployment failed due to a health check failure. This usually indicates that your code was built successfully but failed during a test execution. Examine the logs to determine the cause. Try deploying again in a few minutes if it appears to be transient.

So, I go to the logs and nothing, nada, nisba. Not a line. Tried upping RAM to 2GB, tried packaging .py files that reside at the same level of main.py out of the root, no luck.
Clearly, if locally I call the handler function in main.py from a test script, running it in a virtualenv (py37) with packages from requirements.txt, it works. Running it locally with the functions-framework? It works.

This following is how I'm calling gcloud to deploy so far:

```
gcloud functions deploy load_to_bigquery \
  --project=project-platform-dev \
  --region europe-west1 \
  --runtime python37 \
  --memory 1024MB \
  --entry-point handler \
  --env-vars-file .env.dev.yaml \
  --trigger-resource the-source-bucket \
  --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

Comment: What is your requirment.txt file? There is a known issue in aiohttp and yarl package in python37 environment. https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4880

Comment: @Josan thank you it resolves the issue as the answer from Egor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently GCF is affected by this issue:

[GCF Python37 function deployment fails due to broken external aiohttp/yarl dependency](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162329927)

> A few customers have reported Python3.7 / Python3.8 Cloud functions
> deployments failing for their functions with the following error
> messages:
>
> Python3.7 Runtime: Function failed on loading user code.
>
> " Function deployment failed due to a health check failure. This
> usually indicates that your code was built successfully but failed
> during a test execution. Examine the logs to determine the cause. Try
> deploying again in a few minutes if it appears to be transient. "
>
> There are no errors visible in Stackdriver logs in the customer (user)
> project, however internally we do receive a stack trace against the
> Functions Python37 runtime environment library included for an issue
> with one of its dependencies.
>
> The aiohttp library utilized within our GCF Python37 runtime, uses the
> yarl dependency and the root cause of this issue is a bad release of
> the yarl library)

**Workarounds available before short term fix has been released:**

- Pin the version of the yarl dependency explicitly in the
  requirements.txt file for your Python37 source code, like

  ```
  # requirements.txt
  yarl==1.4.2
  ```
- Another alternative is to use the Python 3.8 beta runtime ( which
  uses a newer / upgraded build procedure that does not require holding
  onto preinstalled packages / libraries ) and as such this issue should
  not be prevalent on the Python 3.8
  runtime: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime